# Inter-process auto-released counter / other synchronization mechanism in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, ipc

I need the following coniditions be satisifed:

1. Some kind of inter-process semaphore / mapped file / or other IPC mechanism.
2. Each process that registers itself in that file (semaphore / other mechanism) auto-releases itself (or deregisters itself automatically) when the process shuts down, disregarding of whether it was shut down normally, or was terminated.

I was thinking of Windows Semaphore, but it does not satisfy condition 2. - semaphore will not be auto-released when some process shuts down unexpectedly. If I use some shared-memory files - each process will also not delete its entry in the file when it is terminated.

Any ideas will be appreciated (Windows & C++).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need condition #2? Also, you can have a separate process that registers others.

Comment: You almost always need an arbiter process to do this correctly.  Most important thing it needs to do is to handle failure of one of the processes when it didn't say goodbye properly, typically requires restarting everybody.  The child processes need to terminate when the arbiter crashes.

Comment: I need condition 2 in order to save program's logic when process terminates unexpectedly. 
But now I see that it is not possible without another process.. Gonna delete this question then. Thank you for your attention!